# Triangle stored as an array. Height and Length of each level?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Assume we have a triangle that each node has K children.

An example for K = 2 is:

```
  1
 2 3
4 5 6
```

An example for K = 3 is:

```
    1
  2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

An example for K = 4 is:

```
        1
     2 3 4 5
  5 6 7 8 9 1 2
```

etc.

1. I would like to store those triangles in an array. I am looking to retrieve the total height of the triangle (assuming they are complete triangles) given the total number of elements T and the number of children per node K
2. I am also looking to find what is the offset for each element in an array to each children. I know that for the example above where K = 2 the array is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] where for each level L the offset is L * (L + 1) / 2 (because Level 1 has 1 element, Level 2 has 2, Level 3 has 3 ...)

EDIT: The example is correct. Each node has access to K child nodes. for K = 3 1 has access to 2 3 and 4. 2 has access to 5 6 and 7. 3 has access to 6 7 and 8.

These are triangles and not graphs or trees.

Comment: Your examples don't show graphs (which you call triangles) with K nodes at each level for each node at the level above. Please state your question more accurately.

Comment: Could you give some further examples (K = 4, 5, even 1?) to make your rule a bit clearer?

Comment: Is you example correct? Shouldn't the last row of the second example have the values `5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13`? I guess your number are nodes and you say that each node have `K` children.

Comment: I think hes saying each node if you think more like trees, in the first one, 1 is the first node, it has 2 children (2 & 3) 2 has 2 children, (4 & 5) and 3 has 2 children (5 & 6).. so, if children is 3, 1 has, 2 3 4, 2 has 5 6 7, 3 as 6 7 8, 4 has 7 8 9 ....

Comment: When you get to K = 4, do siblings share 2 or 3 of "their" 4 children with each other?

Comment: The same applies to every level (apart from the parent level). Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295200/what-is-the-best-data-storage-type-for-a-triangular-array

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have clarified your requirement ...

For K=2 there are

```
1
1+1
1+1+1
...
```

elements in each level, this is the series `1,2,3,....`  If `n` is the level number then there are `n` elements at each level.  Note that this can also be written as `1+1(n-1)`

For K=3 there are

```
1
1+2
1+2+2
...
```

elements in each level, this is the series `1,3,5,...`; there are `1+2(n-1)` elements at each level.

For K=4 there are

```
1
1+3
1+3+3
...
```

elements in each level, this is the series `1,4,7,...`.  There are `1+3(n-1)` elements at each level.

At each level in each triangle there are `1+(K-1)(n-1)` elements.  I expect you can carry on from here.

Comment: Actually the question is more like how many numbers are there in all previous levels given the current level N and the current number of children for each node K

Comment: I know that for K = 2 its N * (N + 1) / 2

Answer (score 0):

The total number of elements `T` for a triangle of height `h` will be:

T = ∑*1...h* (1 + (K-1)(n-1)) 
T = h + (K-1) * ∑*1...h* (n-1) 
T = h + (K-1) * ∑*0..h-1* (n) 
T = h + (K-1) * ((h-1)² + h-1) / 2 
T = h + (K-1) * (h² + 1 - 2h + h-1) / 2 
T = h + (K-1) * (h² - h) / 2

#### Calculating the height

So to get the height `h` you insert the value of `K` and solve the equation. Here's an example of an easy case where `K` equals 3.

T = h + (K-1) * (h² - h) / 2 
T = h + (3-1) * (h² - h) / 2 
T = h + (h² - h) 
T = h² 
h = √T

#### Calculating the offsets

As for the offsets you use the same equation we used to calculate the total number of elements but set `h` to height-1. Here's an example of getting the offset for row 3 in a triangle with a `K` of 4.

*offset*(h) = h-1 + (K-1) * ((h-1)² - (h-1)) / 2 
*offset*(3) = 3-1 + (4-1) * ((3-1)² - (3-1)) / 2 
*offset*(3) = 2 + 3 * (4 - 2) / 2 
*offset*(3) = 5